# How do I convert a mesh and curve into just a mesh?

Tags: mesh, conversion

I have a cylinder that I made into a fish for a fountain ornament.

I made it out of a cylinder and a parent curve.

I want to make that into just a mesh now so I can import it into Unity.

Currently if I import the curve + cylinder mesh it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Just select the mesh then press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. select "Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text"

Comment: Thanks. But as soon as I press Alt+C I get two options:
Curve from Mesh
or
Mesh from Curve

If I select Mesh from curve, the cylinder which was bound to the curve goes back to being flat (not curved).

This is not the effect I was going for.

Comment: Okay I figured out the problem. I was selecting the bezier instead of the cylinder. If I [alt] + [c] on the cylinder and convert to mesh, I can delete the curve and keep the curved mesh. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Convert the curve to a mesh with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

then select the cylinder and the curve (which is now a mesh) by pressing shift and then join both objects by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

Comment: thank you, im new to stack exchange so i dont new how to format

Comment: Thanks. But as soon as I press Alt+C I get two options:
Curve from Mesh
or
Mesh from Curve

If I select Mesh from curve, the cylinder which was bound to the curve goes back to being flat (not curved).

This is not the effect I was going for.